# how to return value from CASE expression into a ALIAS

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to return a value into an alias from a case argument. I've tried various connotations around the following

```
CASE dbo.sch_group.group_code WHEN 'ERDS' THEN '1' AS alias_name
```

but I get incorrect syntax warnings near the alias

Comment: Also work on your accept and voting: 6 answers, no votes, no accepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're [missing an END (CASE on MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765%28SQL.90%29.aspx). This is a "simple CASE expression"

```
CASE dbo.sch_group.group_code
    WHEN 'ERDS' THEN '1'
END AS alias_name
```

If you have more conditions then it would be this

```
CASE dbo.sch_group.group_code
    WHEN 'ERDS' THEN '1'
    WHEN 'abcd' THEN '2'
    ELSE <something>
END AS alias_name
```

I also assume this is in a SELECT or such

```
SELECT
    col1, col2, 
    CASE dbo.sch_group.group_code
        WHEN 'ERDS' THEN '1'
        WHEN 'abcd' THEN '2'
        ELSE <something>
    END AS alias_name
FROM
    dbo.sch_group
WHERE
    ...
```

Comment: I got Incorrect syntax near 'dbo' again, fix above still works. thanks

Comment: @giles: `CASE ..END AS alias` is the same as `alias = CASE..END`. The dbo but is unrelated unless 1. you haven't given full info 2. you aren't doing what we say

Comment: no its a snippit it's a little too big to post here. your suggestion now working with the following as im trying to build a sub query: CASE dbo.sch_group.group_code WHEN 'ERDS' THEN '1' END AS alias,

Answer (score 0):

This is from ORACLE so I'm not sure if it'll work in SQL Server but:

(CASE WHEN dbo.sch_group.group_code = 'ERDS' THEN '1' END) AS alias_name

Comment: I'm getting incorrect syntax near 'dbo' with that (but thanks for comment)

Comment: How about this? (CASE dbo.sch_group.group_code WHEN 'ERDS' THEN '1' END) alias

Comment: Look at the examples on this web page http://www.craigsmullins.com/ssu_0899.htm I've never worked in SQLServer so I'm unable to confirm anything :)

Comment: GOT IT! thanks for those interested its ....alias = CASE dbo.sch_group.group_code WHEN 'ERDS' THEN '1' END,

Comment: @giles: no idea why you say that. `CASE ..END AS alias` is the same as `alias = CASE..END`.